# Isn't there a mistake at the correction? Bas shouldn't turn on when V1 > 0

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, logic-gates, flipflop

[image: Circuit]

So there a table depending on the values of V1, the book solved it like this:

```
+----+---+---+-----+------+
| V1 | S | R | BAS | HAUT |
+----+---+---+-----+------+
|V1>0| 1 | 0 |  1  |   0  |
+----+-------------+------+
|V1<0| 0 | 1 |  0  |   1  |
+----+-------------+------+
```

I don't get it. Is this correct? I have questions about this:

1. **When V1>0**: Why Bas = **1** when S = **1**? It doesn't make any sense. Isn't Haut supposed to be **1** instead since S = **1** and R = **0**? I have the same question about when **V1** is negative.
2. Why S = **1** and R = **0** anyway? Isn't it supposed to be **0** for each of them? Since the result of F1(when V1 is positive) = **1**, then it should pass to S = **1**(Then it becomes **0** since it's inverted) and R = **1** too(Then it becomes **0**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s wrong.

V3 and SR both invert yet LEDs are positive logic.

Even inversions cancel so it is wrong.

Yes for Vi bypassing V3 the FF is negative logic input R and inverted Q out so it is positive logic

Bracket([ inverts negative logic to normal (1)=set ,, ditto reset.

\$~~Vi ~~  \bar{S}~~(S )~~~\bar{R}    ~(R)~~Q~~~\bar{Q}\$
\$>0~~~ 0~~~[1]~~0~~(1)~~1~~1\$
\$<0~~~1~~~[0]~~0~~(0)~~1~~0\$

Due to contention when both RS are active, both outputs are active.

Due to latency in OpAmp lagging S keeps Set active when both SR go off.

The author shud be fired.  No. its a common newbie design mistake.

Comment: Thanks but can I ask you something? What does V3 and SR both invert mean? I thought V3 is the same as V2(Which is F1's result)...no?

Comment: @TechnoKnight F2 opamp is in inverting configuration. V3 = -(R2/R2)V2 = -V2

Comment: @beccaboo Oooh, got it. So negative voltage in SR is equal to 0, right? And then S inverts which means S = 1, right?

Comment: V4 is ideally 0V, not negative. Ignoring the 0.7V diode D1 drop. When V3 becomes negative,  D1 conducts and pulls V4 to 0V. You're correct though. S=1, R=0; then Q=1, Q' = 0 @TechnoKnight

Comment: It is an inverting amplifier therefore negative logic, SR are negative logic too(active low). just count the serial inversions

Comment: @beccaboo So just to be sure, it means that Haut is supposed to be 1, right?

Comment: Q is positive logic out , yes thats haut

Comment: @beccaboo That's all what I wanted to know. Thank you all for helping me! Now I know that the book's correction is wrong.

Comment: This design is AFU FOOBAR

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Notice this little bubble before the S input. This bubble is an indicator meaning that the input is inverted; i.e. a 0 on the input acts like a 1 in a standard SR flip-flop and vice versa. This bubble is the same as the one in the symbol for a NOT gate, so you can imagine it as a sort of miniaturized NOT gate at the input (it's not implemented that way, though).

Many SR flip-flops use inverted inputs, because it just works out easier in TTL, and compatibility means manufacturers keep using active-low designs even though TTL is pretty obsolete by now.

Comment: I know that. But S on the table is 1, so doesn't that mean Haut will turn on not Bas?

Comment: @TechnoKnight S being 1, with the inverted inputs, means that the flip-flop is not being set. R being 0 means the flip-flop is being reset. In the reset state, ¬Q is high and Q is low, so the LED connected to ¬Q would turn on.